# Making a ViewModel work with link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am attempting to use a custom view model in one of my Rails views, effectively replacing a standard ActiveRecord model with my view model, which acts as a wrapper to the ActiveRecord model.

Now when the view invokes the following:

```
link_to(product)
```

This is now interrogating my view model (instead of the ActiveRecord model) to figure out what to render.  I'm trying to understand what the link_to helper is invoking on my model.  I had a look at the [Rails source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for this, but it doesn't seem to answer my question.

So far I've figured out that Rails will call **model_name** on the **class** of the variable I'm passing in, but I think I'm going down the wrong direction.  I thought I would be able to implement something like **to_url** in my view model and simply pass it through to the underlying object.

So how do I make my view model adhere to whatever interface link_to is expecting?

Comment: Maybe this will help: `include ActiveModel::Conversion` defines a `to_model`, `to_key`, `to_param`, and `to_partial_path`. http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/01/07/presenters-to-widgets-with-activemodelconversion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best answer I have found on this topic.

http://pivotallabs.com/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit/